# Does intermittent fasting induce autophagic cell death?

Tags: cancer, immune-system, fasting, autophagy

https://www.cancertherapyadvisor.com/home/tools/fact-sheets/intermittent-fasting-and-cancer/

> In vitro and in vivo animal studies suggest that PF inactivates
>   pro-proliferative pathways, while enhancing differential stress
>   resistance in normal cells.2 Combined with the theory that cancer
>   cells are generally dependent on a highly nourishing environment with
>   a preference for high glucose levels, called the Warburg effect, this
>   resulted in the hypothesis that IF or PF can sensitize cancer cells to
>   chemotherapy or other anticancer therapies. **In addition, other studies
>   have shown that fasting induces autophagy and can modulate the immune
>   system by activating CD8 cytotoxic T cells and inhibiting T-regulatory
>   cells.**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4905302/

> Autophagy is an evolutionarily conserved intracellular catabolic
>   process that is used by all cells to degrade dysfunctional or
>   unnecessary cytoplasmic components through delivery to the lysosome.
>   Increasing evidence reveals that autophagic dysfunction is associated
>   with human diseases, such as cancer. Paradoxically, although autophagy
>   is well recognized as a cell survival process that promotes tumor
>   development, it can also participate in a caspase-independent form of
>   programmed cell death. **Induction of autophagic cell death by some
>   anticancer agents highlights the potential of this process as a cancer
>   treatment modality.** Here, we review our current understanding of the
>   molecular mechanism of autophagy and the potential roles of autophagy
>   in cell death, cancer development, and cancer treatment.

After doing some research, it seems that autophagy plays a role in promoting and combating cancer cell growth, so I was wondering if the first quote above meant "autophagic cell death" instead of simply autophagy, which would make sense because cancer cells fools the body that they are normal to evade immune response. Does intermittent fasting induce autophagic cell death?

Comment: Looks like the term [may be a misnomer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2727358/#:~:text=Also%20known%20as%20type%202,see%20figure%2C%20part%20b).